# How to make Textview will only show the last 4 digits numbers

Tags: java, android, xml

My Textview is getting the data from SQLite, but I want to make Textview to show as follows:
************1234, instead of 1234123412341234.

[image]

Comment: you can so this with some logic also, like setText("************"+data.substring(11));

data is the variable that containing your data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    String number = "grou353fp23g3qprwog9512";
    String mask = number.replaceAll("\\w(?=\\w{4})", "*");

    textView.setText(mask);
```

Output is *******************9512

Comment: if for some reason you want to change it from 4 characters to more, but replace the 4 within the { } brackets.

Comment: Best solution indeed! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String padLeading*(String data, int requiredLength){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        if(data .length() > 4){
data .substring(data .length() - 4)
}

        int numLeading* = requiredLength - data.length();
        for (int i=0; i < numLeading*; i++){
            sb.append("*");
        }
        sb.append(data);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Advantage of this method is that you could vary the number of * as required.  Or to make it simpler could determine the last four characters of the string, pass it in and take:

```
if(data .length() > 4){
    data .substring(data .length() - 4)
    }
```

out of this method.

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin solution**

```
acNumber.replace("\\w(?=\\w{4})".toRegex(),"*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "1234567890";
if(string .length() > 4){
string .substring(string .length() - 4)
}
tv.setText(string);
```

output: 7890

Comment: Thanks for answered,but i want show the output of string like: *******7890 in my TextView

Comment: so you can used this and just add to your string "*****"+string after subString

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code `"*"` in the beginning and extract last 4 digits of credit card num from sqlite and display on text view.

```
String lastFourDigits = extractLastFourDigits(); //I assume you get this
myTextView.setText("**** **** **** "+lastFourDigits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [TransformationMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod.html)
You can use the source of [PasswordTransformationMethod](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.java) as a guide so you don't lose the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Clean and reusable:

```
/**
 * Applies the specified mask to the card number.
 *
 * @param cardNumber The card number in plain format
 * @param mask The number mask pattern. Use # to include a digit from the
 * card number at that position, use x to skip the digit at that position
 *
 * @return The masked card number
 */
public static String maskCardNumber(String cardNumber, String mask) {

    // format the number
    int index = 0;
    StringBuilder maskedNumber = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.length(); i++) {
        char c = mask.charAt(i);
        if (c == '#') {
            maskedNumber.append(cardNumber.charAt(index));
            index++;
        } else if (c == 'x') {
            maskedNumber.append(c);
            index++;
        } else {
            maskedNumber.append(c);
        }
    }

    // return the masked number
    return maskedNumber.toString();
}
```

Sample Calls:

```
System.out.println(maskCardNumber("1234123412341234", "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-####"));
> xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1234

System.out.println(maskCardNumber("1234123412341234", "##xx-xxxx-xxxx-xx##"));
> 12xx-xxxx-xxxx-xx34
```

Answer (score 0):

stringData.replaceRange(0, stringData.length - 2, "*")

I hope it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).